# Removing the .php extension from files with .php/id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php file User.php/100.

In my .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The above redirects the page User/100 to User/100.php.

How do I get it to redirect User/100 to User.php/100?

Thanks.

Comment: on regex101.com you can test regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rule matches the whole path in a single capturing group, then appends .php to the end of the group.

You're trying to insert .php into the middle of the path.  To achieve this, you need to match the part you want before and the part you want after the .php in separate groups.

To achieve this, you'll need a rule something like below:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/\d+)$ $1.php$2 [NC,L]
```

(you might find the slashes need escaping, in which case the regex is `^([^\/]+)(\/\d+)$`)

To explain:

- `([^/]+)` will match 1 or more characters that are not `/`, and store them as group 1.
- `(/\d+)` will match `/` followed by 1 or more digits, then store them as group 2.
- `$1.php$2` will rewrite the match as the group 1, followed by .php, followed by group 2.